# IE11 http status 0 for javascript file

Tags: html, http, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a problem with IE11 only where the main js file wont be loaded/recognized by IE.
The page works fine with IE9/10 and all other browsers. The page in question is [www.kopp-hki8.de](http://www.kopp-hki8.de).[image: developer tools network]

In the developer tools, I see that IE returns a code 0 (????) and there are no response headers. but i can see the file in the response body.
The page does not run any other javascript, even if loaded.

Any hints what may be happening?

Thanks in advance!